# What underpins the argument that commercial paper is systemically important?

Tags: financial-markets, financial-stability

The Financial Stability Report recently had a paper on money market instruments and in one of the sections was a line that read:

> CP rates enter as inputs into credit-sensitive benchmark rates, and
> hence through pricing channels of propagation. Hence the outstanding
> notional value of CP and CDs may understate their systemic importance.

I have a feeling the answer is staring me in the face, but I still don't quite get it.

Perhaps it's something similar to when a credit rating agency downgrades a company to below IG status, triggering conservative institutions who are mandated to hold only IG debt to sell it. This is a mechanical effect. I'm guessing this CP thing is something similar?

### Question

Can someone explain in simple/easy terms what the Financial Stability Board meant by pricing channel propagation and how that affects the systemic importance of the asset class?